# how to check installed application in iphone device in ios SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know the apps installed in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649201/how-to-know-the-apps-installed-in-iphone)

Hi...
I am developing an application in which i need to find the apps which are already installed in iphone device such as Skype, facebook. I need to check it using objective -c ( snow leopard  10.6.2).

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. I'm not sure if there even is a Private API....