# iPhone SDK: List of installed applications?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way I could see with iOS SDK the list of all applications installed on my iPhone?

Regardz,
Mladjo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the apps installed in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649201/how-to-know-the-apps-installed-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Without jailbreaking no, I don't think it's possible.