# Opening an iphone app from PHP/Javascript coded website/page

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, xcode

My question is pretty simple actually... I wish to know if, and how, it is possible to check for the existence of an application on an iphone (twitter app for example) and then pop it open via PHP and/or javascript.

The process would go as follows:

User scans a QR code with his Iphone that links to the page

On the page, php or javascript does some magic to check if, and what, twitter applications exist.

The page then sends a custom URL scheme to open up the desired app (twitter:// for example).

Is this possible? Are there any examples of source code that display javascript/php doing this from within the context of an iphone?

Thank you for any help. :)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649201/how-to-know-the-apps-installed-in-iphone

Comment: Slightly related but not really.. that question/answer set was about going through xcode/native code to check for application availability.. I need to try to do it from inside a UIWebView with javascript/php.  :)

Comment: Thus far, I believe that an application can be opened through created a page link such as "twitter://" which is then intelligently handled by the iphone safari browser. However, I have not been able to find any ways to check if that application exists before hand. 

Can anyone confirm that this is how it indeed works?

Comment: I would be surprised if you would be able to do this (maybe not too surprised much after recent events), since it is a clear violation of the user's privacy IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It would be imposible to check for the existence of an app from Safari.

You may launch an app using a link if the app has registered a protocol. For example, to launch the Facebook app and open it on the user profile you may link to fb://profile.

Here I found a list of some other iPhone apps protocols:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes