# iphone - listing out application installed in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get a list of all the application in iPhone.

There is a website that shows the code on how to do it.
http://amitay.us/ihasapp/index.php

But it doesn't get all the list from an iPhone.

I heard this is possible with Jailbroken phone.

Is this possible if I get the iPhone enterprise library.

I can't find a clue in Enterprise Deployement Guide.
http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the apps installed in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649201/how-to-know-the-apps-installed-in-iphone)