# Objective C:How to get the downloaded applications list in iphone and ipad using objective-c

Tags: objective-c

How to get the downloaded applications list in iphone and ipad using objective-c please help me out!

Comment: It is not possible on a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the apps installed in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649201/how-to-know-the-apps-installed-in-iphone)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it. You can check pre-installed applications and apps with known URL Schemes. Something like this:

```
if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"sms:"]] ){
    //yes, you have this app
}
```

Comment: I find another thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649201/how-to-know-the-apps-installed-in-iphone