# Check if an application is installed or not in no jailbreak iOS device

Tags: ios, jailbreak

There're duplicated questions somewhere but they don't inform that device is no jailbreak.

In there any way to check that an application is already installed or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512228/how-to-check-programatically-if-an-app-is-installed

Comment: HI please check following links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316034/how-to-check-installed-application-in-iphone-device-in-ios-sdk-4-0

Comment: I provided you with an answer but then noticed you have 4 other non-related questions with answers, none of which have been accepted. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library appList to get a list of installed apps and packages, available for free on Cydia (source on GitHub: https://github.com/rpetrich/AppList). With it you can query apps/packages by bundle id. There's an example in the Github repo, or here's a related answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328585/381233.

(I think the OP is correct about there not being questions like his asked here already, the 2 questions listed in the comments currently don't mention Jailbreak.)

Comment: Yes, what I concern is not jailbroken devices.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood the question. But then it's definitely a duplicate.

Comment: ...and then the jailbreak tag is incorrect.